# C++ program requiring libsnappy

Tags: c++, homebrew, snappy, capnproto

I am trying to make and build a C++ program (available here https://github.com/mortehu/text-classifier) which requires libsnappy and Capn Proto. I believe I am having an issue with libsnappy as after running the following commands:

```
configure
make -L/Users/liamflynn/Desktop/Kaggle/Truly_Native/Mortehu/text-classifier-master/tools/text-classifier/capnproto-c++-0.5.3/src 
sudo make install
```

I get the error "base/columnfile.cc:7:10: fatal error: 'snappy.h' file not found"

I have tried linking various folders related to libsnappy in the make stage to no avail. I have also tried to install snappy in a few different ways, such as:

```
brew install snappy
```

and

```
sudo gem install libsnappy
```

But Im not exactly sure where the library is getting saved too. Ideally, I would be able to find the folder containing 'snappy.h' and I would be able to link this in the make stage. Any help with where I am going wrong would be much appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Where are your include paths? -I

Comment: Well, did you read the installation and usage instructions? Did you try to locate snappy.h on your hard drive? Your computer has a "find" function, no?

Comment: I can find the folder with snappy.h. It is ./libsnappy-master/src/lib/core/snappy.h, how do I include this in my make ? Simply with a -L before is not working

Answer (score 1):

The headers are read by the preprocessor.  You can add preprocessor command line flags by changing the `CPPFLAGS` variable.  Use the `LDFLAGS` variable for linker flags:

```
./configure CPPFLAGS="-I/path/to/header/" LDFLAGS="-L/path/to/library/"
```